# MySQL not logging slow queries to table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, monitoring

I want MySQL to treat all queries as slow queries and log them into a table.

MySQL version is 5.1.69. I did the following:

```
set global log_output = "TABLE";
set global log_slow_queries = 1;
set global long_query_time = 0;
```

However, the table `mysql.slow_log` is empty although queries have been executed. Why? The general_log is also enabled and `mysql.general_log` contains all queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with setting those global variables dynamically is that it doesn't affect existing sessions.

Any existing sessions will already have `@@session.long_query_time` set, which will not be over-ridden by `@@global.long_query_time`.

If any new sessions are created after you made the global change, they will inherit the new value, so in that case you should see queries for the new sessions, but not the old sessions.

Answer (score 2):

```
Did you restart the server after updating the `my.cnf` file?

Please issue:

    SELECT @@global.general_log;
    SELECT @@global.general_log_file;
    SELECT @@global.log_output;

These are the de-facto variables as the server sees them.
You may change tgem dynamically as follows:

    SET GLOBAL general_log:=1;
    SET GLOBAL log_output := 'FILE';

Also, as last resort, try:

    FLUSH LOGS;

to close+reopen log file descriptor.
```

Comment: I want to avoid restarting the server. That's why I left the my.cnf file unchanged and I set the global variables instead. This worked for enabling the general log, but it's not logging anything in the slow log.

Comment: `SELECT @@global.general_log, @@global.log_slow_queries, @@global.log_output, @@global.long_query_time` returns the expected values 1, 1, TABLE, 0.00000

Comment: for 5.6 you need to do ```SELECT @@global.general_log, @@global.slow_query_log, @@global.log_output, @@global.long_query_time;```